# measuring how "efficient" is a function solving a problem

Tags: performance, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

Im new to javascript, I remember there is a way to measure if the loop or the function you are using to solve a problem is fast or could be faster, I also remember it was a curve that could be linear or exponential and so on. Does somebody more experienced know what im talking about? i can't find any references to this. `Thank you`

Comment: O notation, complexity theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably thinking of Big O Notation such as `O(n)` for linear or `O(2^n)` for exponential. This is part of the larger subject called "complexity theory".

Hopefully these give you some words that you can google in order to study the topic further.

Comment: actually that is what i'm looking for. Thank you man